# Error using React.memo() over stateless component

Tags: reactjs

Using react 16.6 I am trying to use memo with stateless component but I get an error.

**Error**

*react-dom.development.js:57 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.*

**Code:**

```
const MyComponent = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    TEST
  </React.Fragment>
);

export default React.memo(MyComponent);
```

Comment: I think you need curly brackets `{ }` on the right hand side of the arrow function.

Comment: had to disable prettifier to test that, didn't work (

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should update `react-dom` to the `^16.6.0` version, too.